# Replicate browser and user behavior with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am new on JMeter and would like to get insight on how to replicate browser and user behavior in JMeter.
What is the best practice when using JMeter to test web application (mainly for httpd, php, angular etc)

i.e from some reading documentation I should use timer to delay each sampler for more realistic use case

after reading JMeter documentation, I still have some confusion about:

**HTTP Request configuration:**
- should we use Java instead of HTTPClient4?
- should we enable embedded resources from HTML files?

**Cookie Manager:**
- should we keep or clear cookies on each iteration

**Cache Manager:**
- should we clear cache on each iteration or keep it?
- should we use cache-control header?
- what is the best value for max number elements in cache?

**Where i should put cache manager, cookies manager?**
Under test plan or under thread group if i have more than 1 thread group?

**How to configure keepalive in JMeter sampler or header manager?**

My use cases is to replicate 10 concurrent unique user accessing a web application

Comment: There's no generic answer, and each of these questions can be answered in many different ways, depending on test case and application you are testing. For example "should we keep or clear cookies": sometimes you should keep them, sometimes you should clear them, and sometimes you don't care or don't need cookie manager at at all. Same in all other cases. So start with something basic, and solve problems as they come. SO can only help for specific questions, it won't replace your own learning process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTTP Request configuration**:

- should we use Java instead of HTTPClient4? - **The recommended implementation is HTTPClient4, this way you will be able to use [DNS Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager), [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) with Kerberos, etc.**
- **should we enable embedded resources from HTML files? - Of course, but make sure to exclude "external" ones which are not related to your application, i.e. fonts or scripts which reside in other domain. See [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) for more information.**

**Cookie Manager:**

- should we keep or clear cookies on each iteration **Depending on your scenario, for example if it starts from login and ends with logout - it makes sense to clear the cookies to represent "clean" session**

**Cache Manager:**

- should we clear cache on each iteration or keep it? **Depending on your scenario, like Cookie Manager**
- should we use cache-control header? **Depending on how caching is implemented in your application under test**
- what is the best value for max number elements in cache? **It needs to be sufficient to keep all cacheable content in your application. You can clear i.e. Chrome browser cache, execute your test scenario manually, open [`chrome://net-internals/#httpCache`](https://andreafortuna.org/programming/chrome-net-internals-little-known-but-very-useful/) URL and see how many `Entries` do you have. Amend this setting to be equal or a little bit more**

**Where i should put cache manager, cookies manager?**
    Under test plan or under thread group if i have more than 1 thread group? **These "managers" obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules), if you put them under Test Plan -
 they will be applied to all Thread Groups, if you put them under Thread Groups - they will be applied to current Thread Group only**

**How to configure keepalive in JMeter sampler or header manager? - If you tick `Use KeepAlive` under HTTP Request sampler - it will AUTOMATICALLY add `Connection: keep-alive` header. If you untick it - JMeter will send `Connection: close` header. Don't use HTTP Header Manager for amending [`Connection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) header value**

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, really verbose explanation